Sheaves of sections of vector bundles
If I have two sheaves $E$ and $G$ over a complex manifold $M$ and I want to prove something like say $\mathcal{O}(E) \otimes_{\mathcal{O}} \mathcal{O}(G) \cong \mathcal{O}(E\otimes G)$, where $\mathcal{O}(E)$ denotes the sheaf of holomorphic sections of $E$, why is it sufficient to provide a map $$F_U: \mathcal{O}(U,E) \otimes_{\mathcal{O}(U)} \mathcal{O}(U,G) \to \mathcal{O}(U,E\otimes G)$$ that is bijective? Since this plays well with restrictions $V \subset U$ it yields a presheaf and since sheafification satisfies an universal property this arises a morphism of sheaves $\overline{F}$, but to verify that $\overline{F}$ actually is an isomorphism, one generally can proceed by checking that the stalk maps are injective/surjective.
I know that the stalk maps $\overline{F}_x$ are injective if $F_U$ is injective, but the generally speaking this does not hold when you replace injective with surjective. Is there something about the way that we can consider trivializing open covers for vector bundles that we get around this problem also?

In the smooth category, it is unnecessary to prove things about sheaves locally because of partitions of unity, because they can be used to extend an arbitrary local section to a global section. It suffices to prove that $\Gamma(M,E)\otimes_{C^\infty(M)}\Gamma(M,G)\cong\Gamma(M,E\otimes G)$ as $C^\infty(M)$-modules.

Apologies for that. I'll replace $M$ with a complex manifold instead and consider holomorphic sections. The question is then the same. @QuaereVerum

I assume here $E$ and $F$ are both holomorphic vector bundles.
In general the map obtains by tensorizing sections
\begin{align*}
F_{U} : \mathcal{O}(U,E)\otimes_{\mathcal{O}(U)} \mathcal{O}(U,F) \to \mathcal{O}(U,E\otimes F)
\end{align*}
is not an isomorphism. The easiest example I can think of is the following: Take projective space $\mathbb{P}^{n}$ and consider the holomorphic line bundles $\mathcal{O}(d)$ for $d\in\mathbb{Z}$.
The global sections of those line bundles are given by homogenous polynomials of degree d whenever $d\geq 0$ and in the case where $d < 0 $ we only get the trivial section. Furthermore, we also know they satisfy
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{O}(m) \otimes \mathcal{O}(n) \simeq \mathcal{O}(m+n): 
\end{align*}
Combining those facts we get:
\begin{align*}
F_{M} : \mathcal{O}(\mathbb{P}^{n},\mathcal{O}(m))\otimes_{\mathcal{O}(M)} \mathcal{O}(\mathbb{P}^{n},\mathcal{O}(-n)) \to \mathcal{O}(\mathbb{P}^{n},\mathcal{O}(\mathcal{m-n}))
\end{align*}
cannot be an isomorphism for $m > n $ and $n > 0$ because $\mathcal{O}(-n)$ has no section other than the trivial one.


I know that the stalk maps $F_{x}$
are injective if $F_{U}$
is injective, but the generally speaking this does not hold when you replace injective with surjective.

Actually the implication $F_{U}$ is surjective implies $F$ is surjective at the level of stalks is true. What is not true is that $F$ surjective at the level of stalks implies $F_{U}$ is surjective. (But they are equivalent if we replace surjective by injective).
One counterexample is given by the exponential map on from $exp: \mathcal{O}_{M} \to \mathcal{O}_{M}^{*}$ where you simply take an holomorphic function to its exponential. One can check this map is indeed an epimorphism of sheaves (i.e surjective at the level of stalk) by looking at local determination of the log function.
Now you can consider the following case where $M = \mathbb{C}^{*}$
and the following holomorphic function
\begin{align*}
f(z) = z
\end{align*}
Clearly we have $f\in\mathcal{O}^{*}(\mathbb{C}^{*}) $ but there is no holomorphic function $g$ on $\mathbb{C}^{*}$ such that $exp(g(z)) = z$ as
it would be a global determination of the logarithm on $\mathbb{C}^{*}$ which is impossible.

You still have the right ideas. In order to proof the result we recall that $F$ and $\bar{F}$ induced the same morphisms at the level of stalks and a sheaf morphism is an isomorphism if and only if the the induces morphisms on every the stalks are isomorphisms.
\begin{align*}
F_{p} : \mathcal{O}_{p}(E)\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{p}} \mathcal{O}_{p}(F) \to \mathcal{O}_{p}(E\otimes F)
\end{align*}
To prove that we can simply check for every point $p\in M$ we can find an open set $U$ containing $p$ such that $F_{U}$ is an isomorphism. Let $U$
be a trivializing open set of $E$ and $F$ around $p$ then we have local holomorphic frames
$e_{1},e_{2},...e_{n}$ and $f_{1},...f_{m}$ for $E$ and $F$ respectively.
Using the fact that  $\{e_{i}\otimes f_{j}\}$ is a local holomorphic frame for $E\otimes F$ it follows directly that $F_{U}$ is an isomorphism of $\mathcal{O}(u)$-module.
